# Problem with the package nomencl

Tags: table-of-contents, nomenclature

I'm writing a report for the university, using a format that I found in the web. The problem is when I compile the `.tex` manuscript, the nomenclature does not appear in the output. Additionally, the ToC does not show the nomenclature page. The instructions used in the application Terminal.app. are:

```
pdflatex 00_file.tex
makeindex 00_file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o 00_file.nls
bibtex 00_file
pdflatex 00_file.tex
pdflatex 00_file.tex
```

The `00_file.tex` contains:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,english]{book}

 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{latexsym}
 \usepackage{alltt}
 \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
 \usepackage{titletoc}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{epigraph}
 \usepackage{xpatch}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
 \usepackage[activeacute]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{nomencl}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
 \usepackage{hyperref}                      

 \newlength\ChapWd
 \settowidth\ChapWd{\huge\chaptertitlename}

 \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,122}

 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\filcenter\sffamily}
   {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
     {
     \node[fill=myblue,font=\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east,minimum size=\ChapWd] 
       at ([xshift=-120pt,yshift=-50pt]current page.north east) 
       (numb) {\thechapter};
     \node[rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt,font=\huge] at (numb.west)  {\chaptertitlename};
     }
   }{0pt}{\fontsize{33}{40}\selectfont\color{myblue}#1}[\vskip10pt\Large***]
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}
   {0pt}{50pt}{10pt}


 \makeatletter
 \xpatchcmd{\ttl@printlist}{\endgroup}{{\noindent\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\vskip30pt\endgroup}{}{}
 \makeatother

 \newcommand\DoPToC{%
 \startcontents[chapters]
 \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\noindent{\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth} {1.5pt}}\par\medskip}%
 }

 \setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
 \renewcommand\textflush{flushright}
 \renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize\itshape}

 \textwidth=14cm                
 \graphicspath{{images/}}       
 \makenomenclature          

 \begin{document}
 \include{01_title}

 \frontmatter

 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    
 \tableofcontents            

 \printnomenclature         

 \listoffigures 

 \listoftables  

 \include{03_Experimental}

 \backmatter

 \begin{multicols}{2} 
 \begin{tiny} 
 \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
 \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
 \bibliography{10_references} 
 \end{tiny}
 \end{multicols}

 \end{document}
```

The `01_title.tex` includes:

```
 \setlength{\unitlength}{1 cm}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 %\begin{picture}(5,2)
 %\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm]{UNAM.jpg}}
 %\end{picture}
 \\
 \\
 \begin{center}
 \normalfont\filcenter\sffamily{{\Huge University}\\[0.5cm]
 {\LARGE Institute}}\\[1.25cm]
 {\Large Tiltle 1}\\[2.3cm]
 {\LARGE \textbf{Notes}}\\[3.5cm]
 {\large My name}\\[1.5cm]
 Program \\[0.5cm]
 City - \today
 \end{center}
```

The `03_Experimental.tex` has:

```
 \chapter{Experimental}
 \DoPToC
 The velocity profile at the test zone without any room model must resembles the atmospheric boundary layer given by \citep{daniels} 

 \begin{equation}\label{Uprofile}
 u_z=u_r \left(\dfrac{z}{z_r} \right)^{\alpha},
 \end{equation}%
 \nomenclature{$z$}{Coordinate z [$m$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$u_z$}{Velocity [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$u_r$}{Reference velocity [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$z_r$}{Reference height [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$\alpha$}{Exponent profile [$-$]\nomrefpage}%

 \noindent where $u_z$ is the velocity at a $z$ height, $u_r$ is the reference velocity, $z_r$ is the reference height and $\alpha$ is the exponent profile.

 \newpage
 \thispagestyle{empty}
```

Finally the `10_references.bib` possess:

```
 @book{daniels,
    author = "Daniels, K",
    publisher = "Birkkäuser Verlay",
    title = "The Technology of Ecological Building: Basics Principles, Examples and Ideas",
    address = "Germany.",
    year = "1997"
 }
```

This is the modified `00_file.tex`, with the `intoc` option for getting the nomenclature into the table of contents:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,english]{book}

 \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
 \usepackage{titletoc}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{epigraph}
 \usepackage{xpatch} 
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}                     

 \newlength\ChapWd
 \settowidth\ChapWd{\huge\chaptertitlename}

 \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,122}

 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\filcenter\sffamily}
   {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
     {
     \node[fill=myblue,font=\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east,minimum size=\ChapWd] 
       at ([xshift=-120pt,yshift=-50pt]current page.north east) 
       (numb) {\thechapter};
     \node[rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt,font=\huge] at (numb.west)  {\chaptertitlename};
     }
   }{0pt}{\fontsize{33}{40}\selectfont\color{myblue}#1}[\vskip10pt\Large***]
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}
   {0pt}{50pt}{10pt}


 \makeatletter
 \xpatchcmd{\ttl@printlist}{\endgroup}{{\noindent\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\vskip30pt\endgroup}{}{}
 \makeatother

 \newcommand\DoPToC{%
 \startcontents[chapters]
 \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\noindent{\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth} {1.5pt}}\par\medskip}%
 }

 \setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
 \renewcommand\textflush{flushright}
 \renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize\itshape}

 \textwidth=14cm                

 \makenomenclature          

 \begin{document}

 \frontmatter

 \tableofcontents            

 \listoftables
 \printnomenclature         

 \mainmatter

 \chapter{Experimental}
 \DoPToC

 \begin{equation}\label{Uprofile}
 u_z=u_r \left(\dfrac{z}{z_r} \right)^{\alpha},
 \end{equation}%
 \nomenclature{$z$}{Coordinate z [$m$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$u_z$}{Velocity [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$u_r$}{Reference velocity [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$z_r$}{Reference height [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$\alpha$}{Exponent profile [$-$]\nomrefpage}%

 \noindent where $u_z$ is the velocity at a $z$ height, $u_r$ is the reference velocity, $z_r$ is the reference height and $\alpha$ is the exponent profile.

 \newpage
 \thispagestyle{empty}

 \end{document}
```

I will appreciate enormously all help to resolve this issue. Thanks to everybody.

---

This is the minimum example:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,english]{book}

 \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
 \usepackage{titletoc}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{epigraph}
 \usepackage{xpatch} 
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}                     

 \newlength\ChapWd
 \settowidth\ChapWd{\huge\chaptertitlename}

 \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,122}

 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\filcenter\sffamily}
   {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
     {
     \node[fill=myblue,font=\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east,minimum size=\ChapWd] 
       at ([xshift=-120pt,yshift=-50pt]current page.north east) 
       (numb) {\thechapter};
     \node[rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt,font=\huge] at (numb.west)  {\chaptertitlename};
     }
   }{0pt}{\fontsize{33}{40}\selectfont\color{myblue}#1}[\vskip10pt\Large***]
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}
   {0pt}{50pt}{10pt}


 \makeatletter
 \xpatchcmd{\ttl@printlist}{\endgroup}{{\noindent\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\vskip30pt\endgroup}{}{}
 \makeatother

 \newcommand\DoPToC{%
 \startcontents[chapters]
 \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\noindent{\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth} {1.5pt}}\par\medskip}%
 }

 \setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
 \renewcommand\textflush{flushright}
 \renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize\itshape}

 \textwidth=14cm                

 \makenomenclature          

 \begin{document}

 \frontmatter

 \tableofcontents            

 \listoftables
 \printnomenclature         

 \mainmatter

 \chapter{Experimental}
 \DoPToC

 \begin{equation}\label{Uprofile}
 u_z=u_r \left(\dfrac{z}{z_r} \right)^{\alpha},
 \end{equation}%
 \nomenclature{$z$}{Coordinate z [$m$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$u_z$}{Velocity [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$u_r$}{Reference velocity [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$z_r$}{Reference height [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$\alpha$}{Exponent profile [$-$]\nomrefpage}%

 \noindent where $u_z$ is the velocity at a $z$ height, $u_r$ is the reference velocity, $z_r$ is the reference height and $\alpha$ is the exponent profile.

 \newpage
 \thispagestyle{empty}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: You should try getting a minimal (non)working example, without unnecessary packages and included files.

Comment: If I compile the last piece of code, I get the nomenclature as wanted.

Comment: Me too — make sure you run `pdflatex` twice after `makeindex`.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to run manually the code in the Terminal.app. When I write 'makeindex n.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o n.nls' the system return me: Input index file n.nlo not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that's not reproducible with the presented minimal example

Comment: There is a script called latexmk that takes care of running latex, bibtex and makeindex as often as needed.

Comment: When you wrote `makeindex n.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o n.nls` did you mean your file is actually called `n.tex`? Or did you replace the `n` in those `n.nlo` and `n.nls` with the base name of your `.tex` file? Have you looked in the file folder to see if there's a file there with the extension `.nlo`?

Answer (score 1):

I made a minimal example and it seems to work for me; note the `intoc` option for getting the nomenclature into your table of contents:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature          
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents            
\printnomenclature         

\chapter{Experimental}
The velocity profile at the test zone without any room model must resembles the atmospheric boundary layer given by [xyz]

 \begin{equation}\label{Uprofile}
 u_z=u_r \left(\frac{z}{z_r} \right)^{\alpha},
 \end{equation}%
 \nomenclature{$z$}{Coordinate z [$m$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$u_z$}{Velocity [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$u_r$}{Reference velocity [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$z_r$}{Reference height [$m/s$]\nomrefpage}%
 \nomenclature{$\alpha$}{Exponent profile [$-$]\nomrefpage}%

 \noindent where $u_z$ is the velocity at a $z$ height, $u_r$ is the reference velocity, $z_r$ is the reference height and $\alpha$ is the exponent profile.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I have implemented the 'intoc' but it's not working. I attached my minimal example, which includes the general format of the document.